# How to accomplish this without using eval

Tags: javascript, node.js

*Sorry for the title but I don't know how to explain it.*

The function takes an URI, eg: /foo/bar/1293. The object will, in case it exists, be stored in an object looking like {foo: { bar: { 1293: 'content...' }}}. The function iterates through the directories in the URI and checks that the path isn't undefined and meanwhile builds up a string with the code that later on gets called using eval(). The string containing the code will look something like *delete memory["foo"]["bar"]["1293"]*

Is there any other way I can accomplish this? Maybe store the saved content in something other than 
an ordinary object?

```
remove : function(uri) {
        if(uri == '/') {
            this.flush();
            return true;
        }        
        else {
            var parts = trimSlashes(uri).split('/'),
                memRef = memory,
                found = true,
                evalCode = 'delete memory';

            parts.forEach(function(dir, i) {
                if( memRef[dir] !== undefined ) {
                    memRef = memRef[dir];
                    evalCode += '["'+dir+'"]';
                }
                else {
                    found = false;
                    return false;    
                }

                if(i == (parts.length - 1)) {
                    try {
                        eval( evalCode ); 
                    } catch(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        found = false;
                    }
                }
            });

            return found;
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for eval here. Just drill down like you are and delete the property at the end:

```
parts.forEach(function(dir, i) {
    if( memRef[dir] !== undefined ) {
        if(i == (parts.length - 1)) {
            // delete it on the last iteration
            delete memRef[dir];
        } else {
            // drill down
            memRef = memRef[dir];
        }
    } else {
        found = false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a helper function which takes a `Array` and a object and does:

```
function delete_helper(obj, path) {
  for(var i = 0, l=path.length-1; i<l; i++) {
    obj = obj[path[i]];
  }
  delete obj[path.length-1];
}
```

and instead of building up a code string, append the names to a `Array` and then call this instead of the `eval`. This code assumes that the checks to whether the path exists have already been done as they would be in that usage.

Comment: yes, it works but I would prefer having the validation of the path and the deletion of the object in the same iteration.